# Warning: the running version of Bundler is older than the version that created the lockfile error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, ruby-on-rails-6

When I'm developing/testing, I'm keep getting this error in my console

```
Warning: the running version of Bundler (2.1.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (2.1.4). We suggest you to upgrade to the version that created the lockfile by running `gem install bundler:2.1.4`.
```

It's not blocking me at all but bugging me. I know that easiest solution is just updating my Gemfile.lock to this.

```
BUNDLED WITH
   2.1.2
```

But I want to solve this permanently. I try to

```
gem uninstall bundler
```

and then

```
gem install bundler -v 2.1.4
```

It keeps me giving this error

```
Gem bundler-2.1.2 cannot be uninstalled because it is a default gem
```

and when I try to first install 2.1.4 and then delete bundler 2.1.2 console gives me this output.

```
Gem bundler-2.1.2 cannot be uninstalled because it is a default gem
Successfully uninstalled bundler-2.1.4
```

Is there any solution to this problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try just `gem install bundler` which should install last Bundler version?

Comment: Still giving the same error. But when i try my steps with a Rails 5.2 project it is working. Can be a problem with Rails 6 maybe?

Comment: I had to run `gem update --system`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just run `gem install bundler:2.1.4`, don't worry about the older version that comes with ruby, it should not be used.

Comment: After I restart my console, it works exactly you said. Thank you!

Comment: Still get the same error. This is what I do and still get the error. I've tried logging in and out of console and also rebooting Ubuntu. Just installed rails 6.0.2 in ruby 2.7.0. Also tried upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04 hoping for a hail mary.

Comment: Before running try to delete your Gemfile.lock. It will be created new with selected bundler

Comment: Same problem her, and `rm Gemfile.lock && bundle update && rails s` will still show the same error. Any other suggestion @SemihArslanoğlu?

Answer (score 36):

per Anne van Rossum,
`gem update --system`
fixed this problem for me.

Comment: what does this do, and why does this work?

Comment: after I run `gem update --system`, I found below bug fixes related to bundler:

## Bug fixes:

* Fix broken `bundler` executable after `gem update --system`. Pull
  request #4221 by deivid-rodriguez
* Fix race condition on bundler's parallel installer. Pull request #3440
  by David Rodríguez.

Answer (score 5):

I fixed it!. If you are using rvm, then you have to turn to the ruby version you are using on that particular project (eg. 'rvm use 2.7.0') and then run 'gem update --system'

Answer (score 3):

You need to do the following to ensure the correct default version of Bundler is used for the repo you are working with.

1. **You can run the following but this can present issues as it can break your local gems on your system as ALL of them are updated.**

   ```
   gem update --system
   ```
2. The following method is a much safer way of ensuring Bundler is updated

- Get your gem environment and take note of **INSTALLATION_DIRECTORY**

  ```
  gem environment
  ```
- Then run the following

  ```
  cd <INSTALLATION DIRECTORY>/specifications/default
  rm bundler-<old_default_version>.gemspec
  gem install --default bundler -v <new_default_version>
  ```

3. If you have followed 2 and that still does not work, then run

   ```
   gem install bundler:<new_default_version>
   ```

   to ensure you your local repo is using the correct version

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to update to the latest version:

```
gem update bundler
```

Unless there is a specific reason for using an older version (for example, there is a bug in the latest version, or they are no longer compatible), then you can follow the warning message to just install that particular version:

> Warning: the running version of Bundler (2.2.32) is older than the version that created the lockfile (2.3.4). We suggest you to upgrade to the version that created the lockfile by running `gem install bundler:2.3.4`.

```
gem install bundler:2.3.4
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this was the only error-message being shown on a failed install. I wasted a lot of time trying to fix it, but it turns out **it's just a warning, not an actual error that blocks the install.**

To see the actual error message, I had to run `bundle install --verbose`

Answer (score 0):

Ruby ships with a default set of gems. *Bundler* is one of them. The [default version of *bundler*](https://stdgems.org/bundler/#gem-version) shipped with your Ruby tends to be outdated soon. To update your standard gems, run

```bash
gem update --system
```

See the [*RubyGems* command reference](https://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/) for more information.

If you don't want to update your standard gems, you can also update *Bundler* in the context of your bundle (`Gemfile.lock`). This is possible [since *Bundler* v1.14](https://bundler.io/v1.14/man/bundle-update.1.html#OPTIONS).

```bash
bundle update --bundler
```

---

The times of this warning should be over [since *Bundler* v2.3.5](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/commit/ab1e3e5236f469c5f45d3f821a578335c41c89d6) (January 2022). It now automatically fetches the matching remote version and installs it.

```
Bundler 2.3.17 is running, but your lockfile was generated with 2.3.7. Installing Bundler 2.3.7 and restarting using that version.
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Fetching bundler 2.3.7
Installing bundler 2.3.7
…
```

Answer (score -1):

I removed gemfile.lock file then bundle again to build new dependencies.

https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/3202

Comment: I don't think this will work in a collaborative repo, this could end up creating more problems, so I'd suggest to go with the approved solution instead